# Firebase Auth not throwing User Collision error after secondary Google Sign In

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-authentication

**Question:** How do you work around the bug outlined below?

**Overview:**
I have three (3) types of unique (non-anonymous) authentication available for my app.

1. Email/Password
2. Google
3. Facebook

**App Behavior (steps to reproduce error):**

1. In the initial sign in, no error is thrown.
2. App saves the initial sign in method programmatically.
3. Clear data of App from within Android Settings.
4. Secondary sign in, the following errors (or none) are thrown.
5. Clear data again of App from within Android Settings.
6. Tertiary sign in, the following errors (or none) are thrown.

**Cases:**

1. Google - Facebook: UserCollisionError
2. Google - Email/Password: InvalidCredentialsError
3. Facebook - Email/Password: InvalidCredentialsError
4. Facebook - Google: NO ERROR
5. Facebook - Google - Facebook: UserCollisionError
6. Facebook - Google - Email/Password: InvalidCredentialsError
7. Email/Password - Google: NO ERROR
8. Email/Password - Google - Email/Password: InvalidCredentialsError
9. Email/Password - Google - Facebook: UserCollisionError
10. Email/Password - Facebook: UserCollisionError

**Note:** As for cases 7-10 with initial Email/Password sign, a user account needs to be created from within Firebase console prior to the initial sign in.

Google Sign In seems to overwrite Firebase Auth user account with corresponding email address.

Comment: Is the email address a @gmail.com one? And in case 2 & 3 Email/Password, did you call createUserWithEmailAndPassword() or signInWithEmailAndPassword()?

Comment: The email address used in this one is a @gmail, coz that's the only one that will work with Google Sign In.  To make the situation simpler, I just created the email/password account thru Firebase console. The email/password was signed in using signInWithEmailAndPasword though.