# Firebase Overwrites Signin with Google Account

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

There doesn't seem to be any mention of this in the documentation, and all I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619911/firebaseauthinvalidcredentialsexception-when-using-one-account-per-email-addres) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718466/firebase-auth-not-throwing-user-collision-error-after-secondary-google-sign-in?rq=1), where I would like to confirm this:

> If there is an existing account with the same email address but
>   created with other credentials (e.g. password or non-trusted
>   provider), the previous credentials are removed for security reasons.

If a user signs in through Facebook or email/password and later through Google, their account sign in method is converted to Google. It only happens with Google and the setting for one account only is active.

Is it intended to be like this and is there any way to stop it?

Comment: I found a way to stop it. I have already posted an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717099/ideal-solution-for-firebase-google-provider-login-overriding-other-sign-in-provi/71730017#71730017

Answer (score 21):

As the documentation says: certain email domains have a trusted provider. Most prominently: Google is the trusted provider for @gmail.com addresses, since it's the only issuer of these email addresses.

If a user first registers their gmail address with say Facebook, and later there is a registration with that same gmail address from the Google provider, the latter registration is considered to overrule the former. If the user later signs in with Facebook again, the two accounts can be linked.

As far as I know, the only way to prevent this is to allow multiple accounts per email address.

Also see these posts by some of the Firebase Authentication engineers:

- [Firebase, login by same email different provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46459975)
- https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1180
- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/ms_NVQem_Cw/8g7BFk1IAAAJ

Comment: So this is a feature? Support just sent me: Thank you for letting us know about your concern. We are aware of this issue, and I have communicated your concern to the team. This has been brought to the attention of the right people and is being prioritized appropriately. I can't share any details or timelines at this time, but we'll keep your feedback in consideration.

Comment: Also, if I understood correctly, I'm not using account linking right now. I only allow one account per email in the Firebase Console.

Comment: is there a way to actually alert the user and stop google sign-in to precede over other sign-ins?

Comment: There's a function you can call `FIRAuth.auth()?.fetchProviders(forEmail: email`

Comment: It's not really intuitive that `getRedirectResult` only throws an `"auth/account-exists-with-different-credential"` error when your login flow is Google and then Facebook. If you do it then other way around, there is no error, and the google auth just replaces the facebook one. :(

Comment: That depends on the email address. Google is considered a trusted provider for `@gmail.com` addresses, so gets special treatment there.

Comment: Verified email address will be not be replaced.  As far as other providers: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this? It would be trivial to link multiple social accounts with the same account by email, and this would be a better user experience.

Comment: This is still a problem today, almost four years after. So I reported an issue once again - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5344 @FrankvanPuffelen do you know why it is that Google doesn't trust the email verification at Facebook, because they do now trust the emails given in Apple Sign In, even gmail addresses. So why is Facebook emails not trusted?

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, I used a [blocking function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=2nd). If a user previously signed up with email/password but isn't verified I block their sign in with Google and show them an error on the client.

```
  export const beforesignin = beforeUserSignedIn(async (event) => {
      const user = event.data
    
    
      if (user.email && event.eventType.includes(':google.com')) {
        let existingUser
    
        try {
          existingUser = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(user.email)
        } catch (error) {
          logger.error('Error fetching user by email:', error)
        }
    
        if (existingUser && !existingUser.emailVerified) {
          logger.info(
            `User with email ${user.email} has an existing unverified account: `,
            existingUser
          )
    
          // check if email is unverified
          throw new HttpsError(
            'failed-precondition',
            'Unverified email in existing account'
          )
        }
    
        // otherwise, allow the sign in
      }

})
```