# Login Provider changes from Facebook to Google when loging with google (same email) - Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know why this thing is happening. I am using android with firebase auth. In sign in method Google and facebook are enable only. And I am allowing only one account per email. I am alos not merging accounts.

> What I am doing is :
>
> 1. loged in with facebook. let my email is "xyz@gmail.com" for facebook login.
> 2. loged out from facebook.
> 3. now login with same email "xyz@gmail.com" but this time i am choosing google login.
> 4. now logged out from google
> 5. Now when I again login with facebook and email is same i.e. xyz@gmail.com.
>
> It show an error that user is allready register with difrent auth
>   provider

Comment: Check this post, it explains why this happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766312/firebase-overwrites-signin-with-google-account