# missing 'email' and 'credential' in 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential' error in react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to support both facebook and google login in my app. When user login takes place in the following flow,

Facebook -> Google -> Facebook

I'm facing the error `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential`. I've tried to link the accounts using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015751/firebase-js-api-auth-account-exists-with-different-credential). But I'm not receiving credential or email data in the error as described by the docs. Here is the code.

```
const facebookLogin = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await (LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']));

    if (result.isCancelled) {
      throw new Error('User cancelled request'); // Handle this however fits the flow of your app
    }

    console.log(`Login success with permissions: ${result.grantedPermissions.toString()}`);

    // get the access token
    const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    if (!data) {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong obtaining the users access token'); // Handle this however fits the flow of your app
    }

    // create a new firebase credential with the token
    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);

    // login with credential
    const currentUser = await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);

    return currentUser

  } catch (error) {
    if(error.code == 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        console.log(Object.keys(error))
        const credential = error.credential
        const googleUser = await googleLogin()
        const linkedUser = await googleUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
        return linkedUser
    }
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

`console.log(Object.keys(error))` prints `["framesToPop", "code"]`
The code works if I comment out the part where I try to link the accounts, the user is signed-in as a Google user.

I'm using

```
"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
"react-native-firebase": "^3.2.7"
```