# Firestore + AngularFire - Link accounts

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I want to give user multiple options for signin. For now Google and Facebook.
But when user signs in with Google and later tries to sign in with Facebook, I get an error:

> An account already exists with the same email address but different
>   sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this
>   email address.

So I have to link the accounts. I didn't find any relevant documentation, except for [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) which didn't help much. The best info I could find is here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015751/firebase-js-api-auth-account-exists-with-different-credential) but for some reason it wasn't enough for me.
The solution deals with `signInWithPopup` which gives me this error:

> "Unable to establish a connection with the popup. It may have been
>   blocked by the browser."
>   So if the popup doesn't work, I call signInWithRedirect:

```
private authLoginWithPopup(provider: AuthProvider) {
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
      this.credential = result.credential;
      this.updateUserData(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        this.mergeCredentials(error);
      } else if (error.code === 'auth/popup-blocked') {
        this.authLoginWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
      }
    });
}
```

After Popup, you would go into `then` and could do whatever. But after redirect you lose your information. So I stored it in `localStorage`:

```
this.afAuth.auth.fetchProvidersForEmail(error.email).then(providers => {
  const [ provider ] = providers;
  if (provider === 'google.com') {
    const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    googleProvider.setCustomParameters({ login_hint: error.email });
    localStorage.setItem('auth_error', JSON.stringify(error.credential));
    this.authLoginWithPopup(googleProvider);
  }
});
```

And I retrieve it in getRedirectResult:

```
constructor(
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private afs: AngularFirestore,
) {
  this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult().then(result => {
    if (result.user) {
      this.credential = result.credential;
      const authError = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth_error'));

      if (authError) {
        localStorage.removeItem('auth_error');

        this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            null, (<any>this.credential).accessToken
          )
        )
          .then(user => {
            user.linkWithCredential(authError)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('error', error);
          });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**(This creates another problem. How can I know if it was a normal signInWithRedirect by a user who signed in with Google directly. Or if it was a redirect after user tried to sign in with Facebook and was prompted to sign in with Google because of this error? I don't want to merge credentials every time. But this is smaller problem. But I would love to here solution to this problem also.)**

But the `signInWithCredential` gives me this error:

> linkWithCredential failed: First argument "credential" must be a valid
>   credential.

For which I've found "solution" [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/133):

> When calling `signInWithCredential` with a access token you need to call
>   it like this:
>
> `signInWithCredential(null, token);` If you are doing
>   `signInWithCredential(token)` then you need to use an ID Token rather
>   than an access token.

**I tried both versions, both unsuccessfully**. The second version:
`this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential((<any>this.credential).idToken))`
Type casting is there because there is problem in type definitions I guess.

I tried insert whole `credentials` object, the `idToken` as a first parameter, `accessToken` as a second parameter. But I always get:
**First argument "credential" must be a valid credential.**

As I was writing this it crossed my mind that it probably is problem with `linkWithCredential` and not the `signInWithCredential` method. Which should be obvious based on the error message. I just didn't notice it because google search for the error gave me that solution. So I quickly checked what is in the `authError` variable. There is `accessToken`, `providerId` and `signInMethod` method. There is no `tokenId`. So I tried to send `accessToken` as a parameter, instead of the whole object, and it didn't help. I tried to send it as `null, accessToken`. Didn't help. I tried to find documentation for `linkWithCredential` method, without any luck. So I don't know what it is expecting.

I already wasted four days on this. It cost me much of my mental health. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the underlying OAuth credential (id token or access token): `error.credential.idToken` or `error.credential.accessToken` and its provider ID, `error.credential.providerId`. On return to page, you can re-initialize the credential, something like: `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken)`. After successful redirect sign in with Google, link that credential