# firebase.auth().signInWithCredential error has no email/credential properties

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am getting the error **'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential'**
by using `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(error => ....`

As suggested at :[Firebase JS API auth - account-exists-with-different-credential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015751/firebase-js-api-auth-account-exists-with-different-credential) 
I am catching the error and then do this to resolve the exception:

```
firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(error.email)
   .then(providers => {
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
         .then(user => {
            user.linkWithCredential(error.credential)
         })
   })
   ...
```

The problem is that my error object does not contain email or credential properties. It only contains : code, framesToPop, nativeStackAndroid and userInfo (which is null).

This is my code:

```
const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);

const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

if (data) {
    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);

    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(error => {
      if (errorCode === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(error.email)
           .then(providers => {
                firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
                  .then(user => {
                    user.linkWithCredential(error.credential)
                  })
            }).catch(error => log(error))
      } else {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
}
...
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? If so, can you please answer your own question? I'm having the exact same problem but can't find many similar questions on the web.