# Firebase Same Credentials

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web

I am trying to use Firebase auth.

I've implemented Google Login with no problem, then I've added the Facebook Login, but when I log in using Facebook, firebase gives me this error:

```
auth/account-exists-with-different-credential

An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address
```

I've read this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015751/firebase-js-api-auth-account-exists-with-different-credential), but it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your intention? To be able to login with another provider that has same email id- either you can disable "One account per email address" from Firebase Console, which will create a new account for if user signs in with a different provider having same email. If your intention is to NOT create a new account and merge these two then follow the [account linking process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking)

Answer (score 0):

you could explicitly [allow it](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9134820?hl=en&ref_topic=6386702) in auth management console if you want