# Firebase Auth with Facebook fails if the account already exists and is associated with a Google Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm implemented a simple app containing 2 buttons : 1 to login through Google and the other through Facebook.

Both authentication methods works individually but things gets more complicated when:

- the user has a gmail address and 1st authenticate using the Google Login service
- then, he comes back and tries to login using the Facebook Login service.

Here's comes the error code `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential` that has already been referenced here in stackoverflow [Firebase JS API auth - account-exists-with-different-credential](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44040373/1216281)

The problem is that the `error`object I get doesn't contain a `credential` property name (nor an `email` property name btw) in the little app I've built.

Excerpt of loginWithFacebook.js in the App

```js
export async function loginWithFacebook() {
    signInWithPopup(auth, new FacebookAuthProvider())
        .then((result) => {
            const user = result.user;
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
                console.log(error.credential); // undefined
                console.log(error.email); // undefined
            }
        });
}
```

[link to the testing app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-n58j2e?file=src%2Fapp.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and I was able to overcome it by looking into the `customData` property of the returned error. Probably this different behavior has to do with the specific version of Firebase. Mine is firebase@9.6.9.

So, try to see if this works:

```
export async function loginWithFacebook() {
signInWithPopup(auth, new FacebookAuthProvider())
    .then((result) => {
        const user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
            console.log(FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error));
            console.log(error.customData.email);
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Nice one! thank you so much, man !