# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/account-exists-with-different-credential)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app with react and firebase, this app contain firebase auth.

The user switch between Google/Github Login.

Google login is working fine, but when I login with github it show me this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/account-exists-with-different-credential).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:122:1)
    at _createError (assert.ts:83:1)
    at _makeTaggedError (index.ts:261:1)
    at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index.ts:146:1)
    at async _performSignInRequest (index.ts:191:1)
    at async _signInWithCredential (credential.ts:37:1)
    at async PopupOperation.onAuthEvent (abstract_popup_redirect_operation.ts:102:1)
```

My Code:

```js
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const githubProvider = new GithubAuthProvider();

const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

const loginWithGoogle = async () => {
  const {
    user: { refreshToken, providerData },
  } = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
  dispatch({
    type: actionType.SET_USER,
    user: providerData[0],
  });
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(providerData[0]));
  setIsOpen(false);
};

const loginWithGithub = async () => {
  const {
    user: { refreshToken, providerData },
  } = await signInWithPopup(auth, githubProvider);
  dispatch({
    type: actionType.SET_USER,
    user: providerData[0],
  });
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(providerData[0]));
  setIsOpen(false);
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer.

In firebase console:

1. Go to authentication
2. Go to settings
3. Choose "Create multiple accounts for each identity provider"

Comment: This answer works. But  when user try ever sign in, user taking new uid such as new sign in.

Answer (score 3):

This is (likely) due to the fact that the two accounts share an email address, so Firebase considers them the same user. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015751/firebase-js-api-auth-account-exists-with-different-credential) for more info. Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking).

Comment: I can't find answer that compatible with firebase v9.