# Firebase Auth v9 : linking / merging accounts using the signinWithRedirect method

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, sveltekit

I'm using firebase `auth` to sign in users using **Facebook**, **Google** and **Email/Pass** methods. For the federated providers (Google and Facebook), I'm using the [signInWithRedirect method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#signinwithredirect).
Currently, a user can sign in using one of these methods without issue.

The problem occurs when a user previously authenticated with one provider, comes back later and choose to sign-in using another provider. Then I get the famous [AuthError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.autherror) below:

`auth/account-exists-with-different-credential`

My understanding is that I must [link the accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-federated-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account).

After a few attempts, I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66558928/1216281) about the same issue, but it's implemented using `Firebase auth v8`, not `v9` so it works differently (no `credential` property in the `error` object for example).

So, I understand that once a user successfully signs in, I must store it [as a User object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user) with the associated [OAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.oauthcredential) in the `sessionStorage`. What must happens next, I don't get it ...

Here's how the code looks like up to now ...

### Login part

```js
export function loginWithGoogle() {
  try {
    let provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope("email");
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  } catch(e){
    // ...
  }
}

export function loginWithFacebook() {
  try {
    let provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope("email");
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  } catch(e){
    // ...
  }
}
```

### Handling Redirection Part

```js
import { credStore } from "$lib/stores/cred.js";

let cred; // cred holds the credStore value
$: if (credStore) {
  credStore.subscribe((value) => {
    cred = value;
  });
}


let unsubAuthObserver;

export const auth = getFirebaseAuth();

function getFirebaseAuth() {
  let auth = getAuth(getFirebaseApp());
  auth.useDeviceLanguage(); // use the default browser language

  // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onauthstatechanged
  unsubAuthObserver = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (authUser) =>
    handleRedirect(authUser)
  );
  return auth;
}

async function handleRedirect(authUser) {
  try {
    const rResult = await getRedirectResult(auth); // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential
    if (rResult && rResult?.user) {
      // user signed-in
      const cred = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(rResult);
      // save the user and credential in a sessionStorage store
      credStore.set({ cred: cred, user: auth.currentUser });
      // get info from DB for that user
      getUserFromDB(rResult?.user, redir);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // user tried to sign in using a different method
    if (err.code === "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential") {
      // if something is in the cred store
      if (cred?.cred && cred?.user) {
      // HERE I'M LOST
      // tried to sign in the user with the stored cred from the previous successful attempt
      const result = await signInWithCredential(auth, cred.cred);
                        // ˆ ERROR: credential._getIdTokenResponse is not a function
      

      // get the credential used with the new Provider
      // const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      // console.log(credential);
      // const linkResult = await linkWithCredential(cred.user, credential);
      // console.log(linkResult);
      // Sign in with the newly linked credential
      // const linkCredential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(linkResult);
      // const signInResult = signInWithCredential(auth, linkCredential);
      // console.log(signInResult);
      // console.log(signInResult.user);
      // TODO: Save the merged data to the new user
    } else console.error(err);
  }
}

[...]

export async function signOutOfFirebase() {
  try {
    unsubAuthObserver();
    await signOut(auth);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Thank you so much

## Edit 20/12/2022

Just saw that there's a [sveltekit-auth](https://vercel.com/blog/announcing-sveltekit-auth) out there. I'll give it a try so see if I can manage user auth without `Firebase`. Taking a step back, `Firebase auth` is the only service I use from `Firebase`, so maybe I can manage these cases when a user authenticate using different providers by myself. I'll comment in a few days here.

## Edit 27/12/2022

For those interested here's [a simple implementation](https://github.com/BigBoulard/sveltekit-auth) with Google and Facebook `sveltekit-auth`. You'll see that there's an account linking option called `allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking`. It can freak you out but it all depends on the providers you're using. The problem resides in the case when an attacker creates a social account tied to an email that it doesn't own. With account linking, he would be granted the same access as the email victim. That's why account linking is not an option enabled by default. https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#allowdangerousemailaccountlinking-option. `sveltekit-auth` is still experimental, this means that I can't use it right now. In other words, if I want to get rid of Firebase, I would need to manually implement FB, GG and login/pass auth by myself ...