# Firebase Auth Identifier issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Recently I developing an Android app using Firebase sign in methods like Google Sign in and Twitter Sign in. I used one Gmail account to sign in with different methods, once signed in with Google the Twitter unable to sign in. I delete the account from the console. And then sign in with Twitter but Google unable to sign in. The issue like conflicts of identifiers. So, how deal with same Gmail to sign in the same app, but different sign methods, methods like Twitter and Google Sign, with function sign in and out functions? Please help!

Comment: Please read this link and see how same users are linked "https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking"

Comment: Is this related to this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766312/firebase-overwrites-signin-with-google-account

Comment: Hi bojeil, it is related to that behavior. But what is a collect way to solve?