# Firebase Auth incorrect Error after Google Signin

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If I create a Test User using an gmail email and password on Firebase Auth using `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. and then on a next visit sign in using Google Sign in with the same gmail email using `signInWithPopup(provider)`. Then on the next visit I try to sign in with the same email using `signInWithEmailAndPassword` I get an error code that the

> password is incorrect

Shouldn't the correct error code that handles the case where the email is linked to the google Provider so I can prompt user to sign in with google instead of trying to input email and password. Or trying to reset a password.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an email/password user and then sign in with a Google user, the Google account will overwrite the email/password account (assuming it is not verified). This is for security reasons, as anyone can create an unverified email/password account, possibly claiming another user's email. 
[Firebase Overwrites Signin with Google Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766312/firebase-overwrites-signin-with-google-account)

If you want to link a Google account to an email account, you can first sign in the user with Google and then `currentUser.updatePassword` to add a password. The next the user can sign in with Google or email/password.