# How to link auth providers with native plugins?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm facing a firebase error `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential` when I'm trying to sign in an already existing account(with different auth provider) with facebook. I know this question has been asked many times like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015751/firebase-js-api-auth-account-exists-with-different-credential) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459591/firebase-login-by-same-email-different-provider/46459975#46459975) but all solutions works for web and I'm stuck with native plugins. I'm using [Google Plus](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus) and [Facebook Connect](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook) plugins to sign in on native platforms.

**Code:**

```
async continueWithGoogle() {
    try {
      const googleResponse = await this.googlePlus.login({ webClientId: environment.firebaseConfig.webClientId })
      const googleCredential = firebase.default.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleResponse.idToken);
      const firebaseResponse = await firebase.default.auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
      return firebaseResponse;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('continue with google: ', error);
    }
  }

async continueWithFacebook() {
    try {
      const fbResponse = await this.facebook.login(['email']);
      const fbCredential = firebase.default.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbResponse.authResponse.accessToken);
      const firebaseResponse = await firebase.default.auth().signInWithCredential(fbCredential);
      return firebaseResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        
        // What should I do here?

      }
      console.log('continue with fb: ', error);
    }
  }
```

Can I solve this error without using any web method like `signInWithRedirect()` or `signInWithPopup()`?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-federated-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Its not regarding the plugin.