# How to change the provider for a user in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I've got an app built on Firebase which uses Firebase authentication.

Both Google and Email providers are enabled.

I have a user that had an email login that has somehow ended up with Google as their authentication provider.

They do not want to log in with google.

If I look up the user on the authentication page in Firebase I can see the user in the Users tab and the Google provider listed for them.

How can I switch them back to having an email provider?

Comment: Are both the email and google providers showing on the same account for that user? If so, they should already be able to sign in with either of those accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The Google provider is a `trusted` provider. That means if a user has registered with his email first and later signis in with his Google account it will overrid the first provider. The user won't be able to sign in again with his password.

The only way to awoid it is to enable multiple accounts per email.

You can read more about it on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766312/firebase-overwrites-signin-with-google-account) answer.