# Ideal solution for firebase google provider login overriding other sign-in providers

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been playing around with firebase multi-provider logins. I enabled both email and google.

I've read somewhere that if the email is not yet verified and a user tries to login using google then the user account will be overridden albeit with the same user id.

The reason for this is gmail is a trusted provider and Firebase unlinks the previous unverified email and overrides the data with google user data.

Based from what i've read from this [comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5344#issuecomment-61851891), this is a security feature of Firebase and expected behavior.

My question is how do i handle such scenario when a user has been using his account with email and password and all of a sudden if a user logged in using gmail then he'll no longer be able to login using email and password.

Yes, the user can just simply login using google login and is still the same user account and simply was overridden by google but some users may think this is a bug and not a good user experience.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have a solution that might work for you.

I am using Firebase Authentication for my Android app written in Kotlin. I am not sure what platform and language you are using, but if you are able to transfer the logic, the solution should work for you as well.

For android, you use `GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)` to authenticate the Google account. Here `data` is an object of type `Intent` that has all the required data needed for authentication.

I was able to get the user email from the `data` and if the same email was previously used to login to the app I deny the login and display an appropriate message.

Following is the line of code I have used to get the user's email.

```
val googleUser: GoogleSignInAccount = data!!.getParcelableExtra("googleSignInAccount")!!
```

I hope this points you in the right direction and sorry if the solution is not in the language you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm playing around with it in a web app and using javascript. I'm not sure if there's a equivalent method for getting that method. Maybe this is method is somewhat similar `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`.
Just one clarification, in your approach does it mean you prevent the google authentication if there's already an account with the same email address?

Comment: Yes, the method I have written in my answer does prevent the google authentication if there's already an account with the same email address. `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` will return sign-in providers for an email. I had to use data intent to get the email that was being used to sign in with Google and pass it to `fetchSigInMethodsForEmail`. You just need to figure ou a way to get the email being used to sign-in with Google. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a blocking function to prevent this and show an error to the user to verify their email.

Code example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78149428/5651481